# how to use a counter similar to a timestamp

Tags: java

I have a Node object that contains a field String value and an int field timestamp. 
I would like the timestamp field to be an integer used as a timestamp, that that was incremented each time I create a new node.

```
public class Node {
    String value;
    int timestamp;

    public Node(String v) {
        value = v;
    }
}
```

example:

- timestamp = 0
- `Node n1 = new Node("n1")` -> timestamp = 1
- `Node n2 = new Node("n2")` -> timestamp = 2
- `System.out.println(n1.timestamp);` -> 1
- `System.out.println(n2.timestamp);` -> 2

How can I do that?

Comment: Why not use long as storing milliseconds?

Comment: Is it a multithreaded application? if not, a simple counter is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a static variable, then increment it in your constructor and set timestamp to the current value:

```
public class Node {
    String value;
    static counter; 
    int timestamp;

    public Node(String v) {
        value = v;
        counter++;
        timestamp = counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Best answer. People here is caring about multithreading, and the question is not mentioning that. +1

Comment: @AdamYost Thanks a lot! I used your method.

Comment: @rpax that were great examples of over engineering

Answer (score 2):

While @AdamYost could be correct, there are a problem.

You need `timestamp` to be a static variable, but you need another variable to save the value of the field `timestamp` when the object was created.

So it will be

```
public class Node {
  String value;
  static int timestampCounter;
  int timestamp;

  public Node(String value) {
    this.value = value;
    timestamp = ++timestampCounter;
  }
}
```

With Adam solution you will end up with all objects have the latest timestamp value, according to your output example it's not what you need.

Comment: You added your answer as I was editing mine to give the same info! =P have an upvote for getting yours right first try.

Comment: There is no need to initialize the `static` variable, it will initialized to `0` by default.

Answer (score 1):

To account for multi-threading you need to generate the timestamp (actually generation counter or unique id would be better terms) in a thread-safe manner.

While this could be done using a synchronized static method, in terms of performance an AtomicInteger is probably the best:

```
public class Node {
     private final static AtomicInteger ID_GENERATOR = new AtomicInteger();

     String value;
     int id;

     public Node(String value) {
          this.id = ID_GENERATOR.incrementAndGet();
          this.value = value;
     }
}
```

The use an atomic generator ensures that id's are unique (except for generator overflow) even when multiple threads generate Node objects.